# Getting Undefined, understanding this, that, events, Ionic, google maps and Firebase

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, maps, geofire

I have some code that independently works, but when I put it together I get "Undefined" error at "this"
It surly have something to to with my lack of understanding JS this, that.
I get it to work in Ionic 1, but not in Ionic 2.
I have two events, "MAP_READY" from Maps and "key_entered" from Geofire.
I would we very thankful for guidance. Here is the essential parts of the code:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
 this.LOADMAP();
});
//---------Loading map ----------
LOADMAP(){
 Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
 this.map = new GoogleMap('map', {
  'backgroundColor': 'white',
  'controls':....
...
...
 }
 this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(() => {
 this.GETMARKERS();
}, 
 (err) => {
 console.log(err);
 });
 });
}

//-----Get markers from Geofire/Firebase
GETMARKERS(){
...
...
 var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
  center: [lat,lon],
  radius: 3000
 });
...

var onKeyEnteredRegistration=GeoQuery.on("key_entered",
  function(key,location) {
 this.ADDMARKER(location)
  });
  }
}

//-------Adding marker to map
ADDMARKER(location){
 let markerOptions: GoogleMapsMarkerOptions = 
  {position: location,title:'Some title' };

 this.map.addMarker(markerOptions) <-------------------- This gives error 
 .then((marker: GoogleMapsMarker) => {
  marker.showInfoWindow();
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the error may show here

```
this.map.addMarker(markerOptions)
```

but actual error is at

```
var onKeyEnteredRegistration=GeoQuery.on("key_entered",
  function(key,location) { <---------- HERE
 this.ADDMARKER(location)
  });
  }
}
```

Change your code to

```
var onKeyEnteredRegistration=GeoQuery.on("key_entered",
 (key,location) =>{
    this.ADDMARKER(location)
  });
  }
}
```

'function' will change the scope, that's why 'this' wont work inside the block.
Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Wow! Thanks!! I had no idea, it would have taken me a million years to find out:)